# String sorted in ascending order get garbled

Tags: c

I'm studing c programming language and want to sort string in ascending order. This is c code:

```
/* string sorted in ascending order */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void sort(char *name[],int n); 
int main()
{
    char *name[]={"Zai","Demo","CS","Apple"};
    int i,n=4;
    sort(name,n); // call sort function
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       printf("%s\n",name[i]); 
    }
}
void sort(char *name[],int n)
{
    char *temp;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {      
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(name[j],name[j+1])>0) 
            {  
            temp=name[j];
            name[j]=name[j+1];
            name[j+1]=temp;
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

I use the command:

```
gcc -o string_sort string_sort.c
./string_sort
```

But it can't work.This is error:

[image]

what should I do?

Comment: You have the loop `for(j=0;j<n;j++)` and inside of it use `name[j+1]`. What happens when `j == (n - 1)` (i.e. `j` is the last valid index in the array)?

Comment: Probably `j<n` -> `j<n-1`?

Comment: I know that localization is not high on your priority list at this point, but be aware that `strcmp` only does a *binary* comparison, with e.g. accented characters being sorted after `z`... If you want to actually _sort_ strings, according to the rules of your current locale, you should be using [`strcoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcoll).

Comment: in general, the 'scope' of variables should be limited as much as reasonable.  So, in the sort() function, the variables `j` and `i` should be declared in the `for()` statement, first parameter, not externally in the body of the function.

Comment: @user3629249 - indeed that's a good suggestion but question was just about the failing logic.

Comment: @user3629249 Ok,I konw.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for(j=0;j<n;j++)` has to be `for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)` because otherwise `name[j+1];` will be out of range. With this change, it works. Also, `j=0;` isn't neccesary.

Comment: this answer does not cover all the problems in the code logic

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
```

This line is crossing the bounds of the array. It should be:

```
for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
```

As in the loop `name[j+1];` will cross the bounds when `j` will be just 1 less then `n`.

Comment: this answer does not cover all the problems in the code logic

Comment: User3629249 - please suggest

Comment: @Rizwan,  see the answer by new_learner as it does correct the logic

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void sort(char *name[],int n); 
int main()
{
    char *name[]={"Zai","Demo","CS","Apple"};
    int i,n=4;
    sort(name,n); // call sort function
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       printf("%s\n",name[i]); 
    }
}
void sort(char *name[],int n)
{
    char *temp;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {      
        for(j=0;j<n-1-i;j++) //change at this line
        {
            if(strcmp(name[j],name[j+1])>0) 
            {  
            temp=name[j];
            name[j]=name[j+1];
            name[j+1]=temp;
            }          
        }
    }
}
```